# Safe markup for HTML email

Tags: css, html, outlook, html-email

Email clients are limited in their HTML display capabilities.

What HTML markup and CSS styles is it safe to use in HTML-formatted email?

Comment: A wild lurker downvoted - what a surprise.

Comment: Why does this surprise you? Following stackoverflows guidelines, the question should be downvoted, as "this question does not show any research effort." It has also been answered numerous times before on the html-email tag and can be answered with a single link.

Comment: I was being sarcastic, sorry if you didn't pick up on that. At least justify your downvote then the asker can expand their question / clarify without having to ask.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general you want to stick to 10+ years old HTML.

Avoid trying to link to external stylesheets and avoid styles in the HEAD.

Use inline styles.

Use HTML tables for layout.

Industry standard is to stick to width of 600px or less for your email content.

This is a good guide: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails

Answer (score 5):

Some useful links on this subject detailing which clients support what markup and style:

- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
- http://www.email-standards.org/

Places you can get help building cross-client HTML e-mail:

- https://www.mailrox.com/
- https://www.getfractal.com/